# Регулярное выражение число-месяц

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно избавиться в строке от числа и месяца.
Например, в строке "Рассылка 13 июня" нужно избавиться от " 13 июня". Начало регулярного выражения не представляет из себя ничего сложного \s[\d]*\s,
а вот как дальше добавить список из месяцев? 
Вариант с 12-ью выражениями (например, `\s[\d]*\sиюня`) не устраивает.

Comment: Ну, 12 выражений ни к чему, когда можно `\s[\d]*\s(января|февраля|
 ...  |июня|  .... |декабря)`

Comment: Если после месяца ничего больше не идёт, то \s[\d]*\s\W+ можно вставить.

Comment: @Mike в начале обязательно пробел-число-пробел. Спасибо за подсказку с падежами.

Comment: Пробел в начале ... ну ok. Если конечно у вас не может быть ситуации, что удалять дату надо в самом начале строки (т.е. цифра первый же знак в строке и перед ней ничего нет)

Comment: @Mike, да напишите вы ответ, он уже по сути готов.

Comment: @Николай w малая же должна быть, если большая - то как отрицание.

Comment: @Ajmda я через онлайн конструктор проверял, с большой W как раз "13 июня" и выделялось.

Comment: @Николай видимо, тот онлайн-конструктор считает русские символы за non-word character

Comment: @Ajmda на regexr.com тестировал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил что то в этом роде, только надо еще окончания доработать, в случае если может быть использовано больше падежей:

```
\s+\d+\s+(январ[ьея]|феврал[ьея]|март[еа]?|апрел[ьея]|ма[йея]|ию[нл][яье]|август[еа]?|(?:сент|окт|но|дек)[ая]бр[яье])
```

Пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/icFB6k/1)